# Efficient way of represeting graphs

Tags: graph

I have been learning about graphs on university (as part of Discreet Math as well as in Data structure class). Two ways of graphs representation have then pros and cons as follows:

1. using matrix to represent graph: `O(1)` time to check if two nodes are connected, `O(n)` time retrieve random node connected to certain node.
2. using list to represent graph: `O(1)` to retrieve random node connected to certain node (if any), `O(n)` to check if node `i` and `j` are connected.

This is the way I have been told graph representation works. If it
isn't please correct me.  Now, if above is true, I'd like to give my
opinion.

Matrix is contained of only 0 and 1. So, let's code rows into binary strings and to decimal. Now, we will have array ints where `array[i]` represents node `i`. Retrieving random node connected to node `i` is trivial, and has `O(1)`. Now, examining if node `i` is connected to node `j` is questionable. Now, we need to `array[i]` (being `int` in base 10) convert to binary and check if there is 1 on `i`-th place in binary string. This is done by `O(log n)`.

My question is: are there even more efficient ways of getting this result? What are your thoughts about my idea?

Answer (score 3):

The runtime complexities of the matrix vs. list approaches that you quote in the beginning are correct.  However:

I think `array[i]` in your notation is a fancy way of saying "the `i`th row of the matrix, except it's a bitfield", which does not change the runtime complexity of any of the algorithms.  Why is retrieving a random node connected to the node corresponding to `array[i]` "trivial"?  It is still `O(n)`.  Keep in mind also that if your graph has more than 32, 64, whatever number of vertices, you need an array consisting of something bigger than `int`s.

Checking if there is a `1` in the `i`th place of an `int` is `O(1)`.  You are right that the complexity of finding a random neighbor of `array[i]` goes up if you have arbitrary-precision data members making up `array` (as you will probably need to), but it goes up to `O(n)`, not `O(log n)`.

**Edit:** I made a mistake; with your `array` representation (although note that it is not really precisely defined), checking whether two nodes are neighbors is `O(1)`.  You don't need to "convert to binary" because the computer stores data in binary form natively: you're just describing using a bitfield, and checking the `i`th bit of a bitfield is `O(1)`.

Comment: Let's say you have numbers you need to find random neighbor. That problem consists of finding random place when there is 1 in than number. Name that number a.
int neighbor = int(log (base 2) a). And you will get most significant bit of that integer, which is surely 1.